# gsub not working on colnames?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a dataframe called `df` with column names in the following format:

```
  "A Agarwal"                   "A Agrawal"                   "A Balachandran"        
"A.Brush"                     "A.Casavant"                  "A.Chakrabarti"
```

They are first initial and last name. However, some of them are separated with a space, while other are with a period. I need to replace the period with a period.(The first column is called `author.ID`, and I excluded it from the following code)

I have tried the following codes but the resulting colnames still do not change.

```
  colnames(df[, -1]) = gsub("\\s", "\\.", colnames(df[, -1]))
  colnames(df[, -1]) = gsub(" ", ".", colnames(df[, -1]))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `colnames(df) <- sub("\\s+", ".", colnames(df))`

Comment: Amazing. What are the differences between the two other than gsub? What does the `+` mean?

Comment: Or use `fixed = TRUE`: `gsub(" ", ".", "A Agarwal", fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: I think it is not that important if `\s` or `\s+` is used, or `fixed=TRUE` with a space - that can all be adjusted (if you just need to replace 1 literal space with a dot, yes, `sub(" ", ".", colnames(df), fixed=TRUE)` should be used). The `[,-1]` means you get all rows and all columns except the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `df[, -1]` gets you all rows and columns except the first column (see [this reference](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Index-vectors)). In order to modify the column *names* you should use `colnames(df)`.

To replace the first literal space with a dot, use

```
colnames(df) <- sub(" ", ".", colnames(df), fixed=TRUE)
```

If there can be more than one whitespace, use a regex:

```
colnames(df) <- sub("\\s+", ".", colnames(df))
```

If you need to remove all whitespaces sequences with a single dot in the column names, use `gsub`:

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("\\s+", ".", colnames(df))
```